# yii accessRules by IP address

Tags: php, yii

I'm using **Yii 1.1.16**, and am trying to add an `accessRules` to filter by IP

This is my code in my `CommentsController`. It still allows my localhost IP to access the action. Other than my actions, this is the only other function in my controller.

What am i missing or doing wrong? Thanks

```
public function accessRules() {
    return array (
        array ('allow', // allow all users to perform these actions
            'actions' => array ( 'Comments' ),
            'ips' => array(
                /*"127.0.0.1",*/ /* localhost */
                /*"::1",*/ /* localhost */
                "52.XX.XX.XX" //live site
            )
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to add a `deny` too:

```
......
public function filters()
{
   return array(
       'accessControl', //access control filter should be applied to every action of the controller
   );
}

public function accessRules() {
    return array (
        array ('allow', // allow all users to perform these actions
            'actions' => array ( 'comments' ),
            'ips' => array("52.XX.XX.XX")
        ),
        array ('deny', //deny by default
                'ips' => array("*")
            ),
    );
}
```

The reason for having a `deny` rule is because if none of the rules matches a context, then the `deny` rule gets executed. More info [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter).

Comment: i had to add this `public function filters() {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        );
    }`

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code.

```
//controller file.

public function filters()
{
    return array( 'accessControl' ); // perform access control for CRUD operations
}

public function accessRules() {
    return array (
        array ('allow', // allow all users to perform these actions
            'actions' => array ( 'Comments' ),
            'ips' => array(
                "52.XX.XX.XX" //live site
            )
        ),
        array ('deny', // deny all users to perform these actions
            'actions' => array ( 'Comments' ),
            'ips' => array('*')
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: i had to add this `public function filters() {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        );
    }`